# in angularJS, how to render model containing markup as markup (unescaped)

Tags: angularjs, markdown, angularjs-filter

Im trying to make a markdown editor with preview via angular filter calling showdown

```
<textarea ng-model="data.text"></textarea>
<div class="preview">{{data.text|markdown}}</div>
```

I managed to convert markdown markup on the fly into html but when rendered the actual output on the screen is like this :

> `<h1 id="thisisaheader">This is a header</h1>`

It looks like the resulting markup is escaped. how do i render it unescaped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`:

```
<div class="preview" ng-bind-html-unsafe="data.text|markdown"></div>
```

It's up to you to guarantee that the content is trustful.

If you happen to be using Angular 1.2 RC1, then you should use `ng-bind-html` along with the new [Strict Contextual Escaping](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce) service (`$sce` for short).

Comment: Thx for this Michael, works great. Just curious, this would mean i would have to set bind the data.text to a wrapper div, is there any way i can still retain the {{data.text|markdown}} usage? maybe set something in my filter?

Comment: I don't think that's possible because the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive works by setting the `innerHTML` property of the element it is applied with the result of its expression. You can use any tag you like to be the wrapper, though.